# the following class could not be instantiated?

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus-one

i was trying to integrate google +1 option in my app.
i imported google play services library in ma app and i did all previous steps like enabling g+ api  xml .When i try to add google plus button in xml file,i am getting following error

```
         The following classes could not be instantiated:
          - com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)               
          See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

Comment: See the error log for more details... The most likely reason is that you did not include this framework in your application.

Comment: @MattClark  'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton failed to instantiate'   this is the error message

Comment: That is descriptive... Yay Google! Did you include the .jar file in your application? Is there any more information provided by LogCat?

Comment: @MattClark ya i imported library.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with TitlePageIndicator.
My reason - wrong class definition in manifest. (Copy/past error during update project).